# Unable to Display Welcome HTML Page in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am facing an issue with displaying a welcome HTML page in my Spring Boot application. Despite configuring the controller and placing the HTML file in the correct location, the welcome page is not rendering as expected. Here are the details:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public String showWelcomePage() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring Boot HTML Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Spring Boot!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML File Location:
The index.html file is located in the src/main/resources/templates directory.

Problem:
When accessing http://localhost:8080/welcome, I encounter a 404 error, and the welcome page is not displayed. I have restarted the application, verified the file names, and checked the console logs, but the issue persists.

I am new to Springboot,
Can anyone help me identify the root cause of this issue? Am I missing any configuration or is there a common pitfall I should be aware of when rendering HTML pages in Spring Boot? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us your Spring configuration class.
You might also try return "templates/index";

Answer (score 1):

Here is one configuration pitfall you should be aware of:

The controller class need to be in a package which will be scanned by Spring. By default the package of the main application class and its sub-packages will be scanned. Otherwise you will need to add a `@ComponentScan` annotation.